# .NET get BindingSource value from Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

I have some controls on a tablelayout and every control has a bound value (coming from a DataTable and bound with an `BindingSource`). My application hides some controls after interaction and I want the value of every hidden control set to `null` or `DBNull.Value` if the bound control turned invisible.

Basically I have a loop which goes through all controls in my tablelayout.

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control c in tablelayout.Controls)
{
    if (c.Visible == false && c.DataBindings.Count > 0)
    {
        Binding binding = c.DataBindings[0]; // only one binding per control
        // here I would do something like (object)binding.Value = null; 
    }
}
```

**Is this possible?** My last solution would be to just manually change the value of every control I turned invisible...

Comment: You should check the Binding's [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format) and [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse) events. -- Note that each time these events are raised, the `sender` object is the Binding. Its `Control` property references the bound Control. You can verify the Control's `Visible` state, then set or return a value depending on this *status*.

Comment: These events are commonly used for what you're describing, to handle values that need special formatting or parse values that are not directly supported by either the data source or a Control (e.g., a Null / DBNull value applied to a DateTimePicker).

Comment: I found a way: inside the foreach I set ```c.Text = null``` and after that I called ```bindingSource.EndEdit()``` which forces the binding to redraw. This worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control c in tablelayout.Controls)
{
    if (c.Visible == false && c.DataBindings.Count > 0)
    {
        c.Text = null; // sets the Text to null
        bindingSource.EndEdit(); // redraws the BindingSource, so its committing the new value
    }
}
```